# How to create react native wrappers for native android and iOS SDKs

Tags: react-native, android-library, ios-library, react-native-modules

I am creating a React Native module as a wrapper for existing Android and iOS libraries. The Android library is a jar file and the iOS library is xcframework file. I put the xcframework file inside the ios folder, and the jar file inside android/libs folder ( I created the libs folder). I first tried the iOS library by adding s.preserve_path, s.xcconfig and s.vendored_framework inside the project level podspec file. I am not sure if I need to do anything for the pod spec file, like running it. So I just went along with the next step by trying to import the library's .h in .m file. I tried both using angle brackets <> and using quotes "". But none worked, because firing "react-native run-is" gave me this error: fatal error: file not found. Any help on how to include the libraries in react native is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the error by doing the following two steps:

1. Change "s.vendored_framework" to "s.vendored_frameworks" in the project level .podspec file. My original one is singular (framework), not plural (frameworks).
2. cd iOS && pod install && cd ..

Step 2 can be found in create-react-native-module's GitHub link:
https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module

I missed the second step when posting my question. I thought then that if I ran "react-native run-ios", it would run "pod install".

Comment: However, the Android version still won't build. The issue is that the android/build.gradle still uses maven plugin, while for Gradle 7, maven is replaced with maven-publish. But just by changing this and a few other things still won't fix the build issue. It comes down to this line: classpath += files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList().  "compile" cannot be found. Changing it to "implementation" gave the error: configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.  Someone has reported the issue in the GitHub page, but it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

For creating react native wrapper or node module you need use below library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-library

https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module

Using this library you can create empty react native module project after that you can bind your native code ARR or framework files into that project.

Comment: Thank you for the links. But I already created my empty react native module using create-react-native-mudule when I posted my question. The problem I have is that after I put my .xcframework and .jar library, and for iOS specifically, modified the project podspec file as I did in my question and tried to import my library in the .m file, the project failed to run when I cd to example and typed in "react-native run-ios". For Android, it didn't run even just after I created the empty project. I think there is some setup to be done on Android.